# Where should we be storing the MD5 hashkey for our .Net applications?

Tags: c#, .net, md5

We have several Net applications (Winforms and Asp.Net) and use .Net MD5Encryption to encrypt/decrypt user login information. We are using a GUID as the hashkey and store that key in the source of the application. Is this a security vulnerability to do so? Is there a better practice for handling this?

Comment: MD5 is not an encryption algorithm, and it isn't even a secure hash algorithm. What are you _doing_ in particular? (Do you have a reference for this ".NET MD5Encryption"?)

Comment: It's not really a security vulnerability any more than deleting the key or storing the credentials in plaintext. MD5 can be collision-cracked in a matter of hours or minutes on the right hardware

Comment: MD5 issues aside, storing anything related to encryption or hashing is a security vulnerability: anyone with access to this GUID would be able to guess a good deal of passwords using a rainbow table attack if they get access to the hashes (a big if).

Comment: @Charlieface - pls keep it civil. How else do we learn things unless we post questions and get answers from those with more experience/knowledge?

Comment: We can't give you a good answer because you haven't told us what the problem is. MD5 is a message digest; it was designed as a quick way to get a lookup hash or checksum of long strings and it is good at that. It was never designed for security or encryption uses and is not good for doing them. Please explain what you will be doing with these hashes.

Comment: Sorry didn't mean to come off sharp. I was just trying to say that protecting MD5 password hashes seems like an exercise in futility. If you switch to a more secure algorithm, yes you need to keep your hash secret, which is not trivial and basically impossible against anyone with administrator access to the machine.

Comment: `How else do we learn things unless we post questions` Research. Asking questions is generally just going to get you a second hand digest.  No One could possibly tell you everything you need to know about cryptography, hashing ir best practices with regards to secrets in apps.

Comment: @Charlieface - NP, No Worries. Haven't needed to do much with security vulnerabilities, so really kind of starting at ground zero. Inherited some applications and trying to figure best method for securing them. Asp.Net app is hosted on Azure. Underlying SQL DBs are hosted on Azure as well. Was hoping for ideas/suggestions to follow up on my own.

Comment: From your other comment: "is simply using MD5 to scramble the password which is stored in SQL DB" – switch to a modern password storage scheme, such as scrypt or pbkdf2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider this similar to publishing the hashing details in your documentation.  Keeping the details of *how* you hash passwords secret is at-best defense-in-depth, at worst security-though-obscurity.

A bad actor can't attack any passwords you've hashed unless they *also* have access to your stored hashes.

Comment: So to be clear.., having that GUID embedded in code is a bad thing. We are eventually looking to Azure Key Vault for secret/password storage. The current (inherited) application is simply using MD5 to scramble the password which is stored in SQL DB.  What can we do in the short term to make this more secure?

Comment: The SQL DB is your single point of defense.  So ensure that the WinForms users can't read the hashes.  If they must connect directly, DENY SELECT on the table, and access it only through a stored procedure.